# Get output name in cmake with $@

Tags: cmake

I was wondering if in cmake we can do something like

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT some_folder/some_program
        COMMAND c++ ./main.cpp -o $@)
```

as in `make` the token `$@` is supposed to be the output file (target) - in this case it is `some_folder/some_program`.

In `make` we have these special variables `$<, $1, $@`. In `cmake` I tried it out but I get weird results.

---

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CMake there is **no automatic variables** which refers to current command's **output** file or **input**.

If you don't want to duplicate things, you may create variable which contains output file. Or create function/macro which wraps whole `add_custom_command` call:

```
function(compile_me target_file)
    add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${target} COMMAND c++ -o ${target} ${ARGN})
function()

compile_me(some_folder/some_program main.cpp)
```